# How to render an offline page with Node.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I recently came across a cool feature on LinkedIn website.
This feature allows you to render a page even if you're offline.

I would like to know if this is possible with **Express.js** or **JavaScript**.

Thanks for reading!!!

Comment: About possibility, what can't be done in this world,what have  you tried so far to do this?

Comment: This is done by creating a PWA (Progressive web app). See https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/

Comment: Well (providing it's hosted remotely) it wouldn't be possible to communicate with the server, so the Node.js part is no applicable. But in your client-side, you can watch `window.navigator.onLine` for changes, and update the frontend accordingly. This would only work if the site is already open, otherwise you'll need to use SW and in a PWA.

Comment: I have gotten the answer. I used a service worker. The answer is explained in a detailed manner [here](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/). Thank you for the comments.